# No Available release found

Tags: 7, updating

On the module update area, my install of 7.56, can seem to find matches to core and a few modules.

How do I begin to fix this?

[image]

### What I've tried so far:

Based on translating an answer in  [Cannot update drupal8: “No available releases found”](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232520/cannot-update-drupal8-no-available-releases-found) to v7, I attempted

```
drush vdel update_last_check -y
drush rf
drush cc all
drush cron
```

This failed to do anything meaningful.

Comment: You usually use `drush ups` to scan for module updates. (And you can also click _check manually_ at the top of the overview.

Comment: You don't happen to have a module called httprl installed, do you? That used to block update checks for me until I removed it.

Comment: @Kevn, no `$ drush pml | grep httprl` showed nothing.

Comment: @Neograph734 I've been running `drush rf @sites -y` and `drush @sites up -y` regularly. But this UI inconsistency is bothering me.

Comment: It depends a bit on how long it lasts... I see this occasionally. (When the Drupal servers are busy or something.) After I adjusted my cron jobs from running on the whole hour to running 12 minutes after every hour, it was reduced. And usually checking it a little later solves it. Personally I never worry about it too mush (unless it persists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing helped in our case, but running the following command:

```
drush sql-query "truncate cache_update"
```