# What to do when Drupal can't check for updates?

Tags: 8, updating

I am trying to check for updates using the core update module but I keep getting this error:

> There was a problem getting update information. Try again later.

I am checking from `/admin/reports/updates`.  When I press "Check manually," the screen quickly skips through the progress bar and then immediately returns the error (there are dozens of modules installed, so it normally isn't that fast).

The "Recent log messages" report has no information.

I'm trying to do this from a multidev environment in Pantheon; until a few hours ago, update checks were working fine, but after I created some new environments, it seems that I can no longer check for updates.

Uninstalling and re-enabling the update module does not fix the problem.

Comment: Check your server error logs for anything related to network failures, otherwise you'll probably have to open a ticket with Pantheon.

Comment: @Clive Ugh, I just remembered this bug: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232520/cannot-update-drupal8-no-available-releases-found