# The hacked module report is not able to fetch the information of the enabled modules on the site

Tags: 9

I am trying to use the Hacked module report for a site audit. However it has trouble fetching the data of the available modules on the site.

When tried using the drush  commands of hacked module, I am getting the following errors.

```
Unable to decode output into JSON: Syntax error                              
                                                                               
  TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Drupal\hacked\HackedProjectWebDevDownloader  
  ::gitClone() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/htm  
  l/www/modules/contrib/hacked/src/HackedProjectWebDevDownloader.php on line   
  70 in Drupal\hacked\HackedProjectWebDevDownloader->gitClone() (line 100 of   
  /var/www/html/www/modules/contrib/hacked/src/HackedProjectWebDevDownloader.  
  php).
```

I am also getting the following errors related to fetching of modules.

```
>  [error]  Could not download project: drupal 
>  [error]  Could not hash remote project: drupal 
>  [error]  Could not download project: drupal 
>  [error]  Could not hash remote project: drupal 
>  [error]  Could not hash local project: drupal 
>  [notice] Finished processing: drupal
```

The same site is also having trouble fetching the list of available udpates.

Reference in drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked/issues/3385655

Comment: The patch from https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked/issues/3385655 was applied by maintainers. Can you try the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by implementing the instructions in  the following

[Cannot update: "No available releases found"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232520/cannot-update-no-available-releases-found)